# Why is the resulting value of a combination of logical operations contradict each of them separately?

Tags: javascript, logic, logical-operators

### My JS code for displaying modal window in depending of values.

When I output values of `event.pageY < 30`, `isMovingUp(event)`, `event.movementY < 0` separetly all of them equals `true` but `event.pageY < 30 && event.movementY < 0 && isMovingUp(event)` equals `false`. Why it so?

```
const showModalBeforeOut = (event) => {
  const headerBlock = document.querySelector("#header");

  console.log(`${event.pageY < 30}`);
  console.log(`${isMovingUp(event)}`);
  console.log(`${event.movementY < 0}`);

  if (event.pageY < 30 && event.movementY < 0 && isMovingUp(event)) {

    console.log(`logical value of expression is: ${event.pageY < 30 && isMovingUp(event) && event.movementY < 0}`);

    let modalTextContent = "Don't leave the site!";
    let isCookieExists = checkCookie('max-age')
    if (!isCookieExists) {

    // if there is no cookie here at first display modal window and after initialize cookie with value `max-age`
      displayPopup(modalTextContent);
      document.cookie = 'max-age=15'

      if (document.body.contains(document.querySelector('.question-p'))) {
        const targetElement = document.querySelector('.question-p')
        targetElement.textContent = "Leaving already?"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing console.log(`${event.pageY < 30}`); instead of console.log(event.pageY < 30)? Perhaps you aren't logging what you think you are logging.

Comment: You're creating a string using `` template literals

Comment: Also what is isMovingUp

Comment: @Emil Karlsson For more convenient tracking by signatures like this ```console.log(`some_text: ${event.pageY < 30}`);```

Comment: Well there's your problem. You reset coordinatePageY outside of the function. That means it isn't 0 the second time you run the function.

Comment: @mplungjan Added it

Comment: @Sergey_nd And then deleted it again, it seems.

Comment: @Emil Karlsson This is is a conceived approach because I initialize the variable initially and then compare each time with the previous value out of function

Comment: That is (in my view) bad praxis. Within a function, you should only use variables that were sent in to the function through the parameters. But if you absolutely want to do it the way you do it, then you should not be surprised that the function gives different results at different times, despite having the exact same input.

Comment: @Emil Karlsson Absolutely agree. This approach is used only because I have not come up with a better one.

Comment: And that is okay. If you want to ensure that you get the same result both in the console.log and in the if-statement, I suggest that you do something like: const MOVING_UP = isMovingUp(event); and then use that constant in both the console.log and the if-statement.

Comment: @Emil Karlsson Thanks a lot! Works with the expected result.